# How can I set a NanoPi's GPIO as output on hardware level?

Tags: c++, mmap, gpio

I'm trying to set the **Pin G11** on a NanoPi Neo, previously configured as input, to output in C++ by mapping the PIO function register into the virtual memory with `mmap` and setting a single bit.

Per [Allwinner H3 Datasheet](http://wiki.friendlyarm.com/wiki/images/4/4b/Allwinner_H3_Datasheet_V1.2.pdf) the following hardware addresses are specified:

> PIO Base Address: 0x01C20800 (p. 316)
>
> PG Configure Register 1 offset: 0xDC (p. 338)
>
> PG11 bits: 14:12

Similar to the Raspberry Pi's function register, the Pin knows at least two states:

```
000: input
001: output
```

In my Script, I'm therefore trying to set the 12th bit of the *PG Configure Register 1*.
Here's my C++ code:

```
struct peripheral {
    unsigned long addr_hardware;
    int map_size;
    int mem_fd;
    void *mem_map;
    volatile unsigned long *addr_virtual;
    
    int map() {
        if ((mem_fd = open("/dev/mem", O_RDWR | O_SYNC)) < 0) return -1;
        // map addr_hardware=0x01C20000 into /dev/mem
        if ((mem_map = mmap(0, map_size, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, mem_fd, addr_hardware)) == MAP_FAILED) return -1;
        // store virtual address with offset of 0x800, which was rounded down before
        addr_virtual = (volatile unsigned long *) mem_map + 0x800;
        return 0;
    };
    void unmap() {
        munmap(mem_map, map_size);
        close(mem_fd);
    };
};

int main() {
    // initialize peripheral at rounded down PIO base address
    peripheral gpio {0x01C20000, 4096 * 10};
    // map PIOs into virtual memory
    if (gpio.map() == -1) return -1;

    // output current value of PG Configure Register 1
    cout << bitset<32>(*(gpio.addr_virtual + 0xDC)) << endl;
    // set 12th bit
    *(gpio.addr_virtual + 0xDC) |= (1 << 12);
    // output value of register after setting the 12th bit
    cout << bitset<32>(*(gpio.addr_virtual + 0xDC)) << endl;

    gpio.unmap();
    return 0;
}
```

Unfortunately, my code does not work. When I run the script again, the content of the PIO Configure Register has changed to its previous state. When I configure the Pin G11 as Output (via WiringNP), the displayed value doesn't change. I'm checking the proper functionality of my code with an LED (it should turn on when state is changed from IN to OUT because it is set to HIGH).

When I alter the `map_size`, I get the following results (spaces added for better readability):

```
> gpio {0x01C20000, 4096 * 2}
< 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
< 00000000 00000000 00010000 00000000

> gpio {0x01C20000, 4096 * 10}
< 00000000 00000000 00000000 00110011
< 00000000 00000000 00000000 00110011
```

I am expecting the following result:

```
> gpio {0x01C20000, 4096 * 10}
< 00000000 00000000 00000000 00110011
< 00000000 00000000 00010000 00110011
```

Comment: Have you managed to solve it? I'm facing the same issue with the same chip.

Comment: @felipeduque yes I did. I will post an answer to share my solution. Let me know whether this solves your problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve my problem, I had to change the virtual address used to access the PIO hardware in the following way:

```
addr_virtual = (volatile unsigned long *) mem_map + (0x800 >> 2);
```

which equals the shortened statement:

```
addr_virtual = (volatile unsigned long *) mem_map + 0x200;
```

but is more readable, as the PIO hardware address is `0x01C20000 + 0x800`. I also went with a map size of `4096 * 10` bytes.

I am using these macros for I/O-operations:

```
#define GPIO_IN(g) *(gpio.addr_virtual + (((((g) / 32) * 36) + ((((g) - ((g) & ~31)) / 8) * 4)) >> 2)) &= ~(7 << ((((g) - (((g) / 32) * 32)) - ((((g) - (((g) / 32) * 32)) / 8) * 8)) * 4))
#define GPIO_OUT(g) GPIO_IN(g); *(gpio.addr_virtual + (((((g) / 32) * 36) + ((((g) - ((g) & ~31)) / 8) * 4)) >> 2)) |= 1 << ((((g) - (((g) / 32) * 32)) - ((((g) - (((g) / 32) * 32)) / 8) * 8)) * 4)

#define GPIO_SET(g) *(gpio.addr_virtual + (((((g) / 32) * 36) + 0x10) >> 2)) |= 1 << ((g) - (((g) / 32) * 32))
#define GPIO_CLR(g) *(gpio.addr_virtual + (((((g) / 32) * 36) + 0x10) >> 2)) &= ~(1 << ((g) - (((g) / 32) * 32)))
```

Comment: My mmap pointer type is uint32_t. So if the actual GPIO offset is 0x800 bytes, the offset in my "pointer space" is 0x800 / 4 = 0x200, since each uint32_t takes 4 bytes. I wonder why this is the same value you found for your unsigned long type...

Comment: (BTW, it works now, though I had figured that out by looking at [this lib](https://github.com/luoyi/h3-gpio).)

Answer (score 0):

if pio is defined in device tree, the kernel will control and overwrite related registers. for example if it want to drive a blinking led or other io via this registers.